# Serving Angular Universal Application results in NetworkError

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I get a network error when running my Angular Universal application. After some research I found out that this is related to the relative paths in my application. Unfortunately, it is not clear to me how to fix the error. As far as I understand, the paths in the tsconfigFiles need to be adjusted. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks a lot

### Terminal output

```
 ERROR NetworkError
        at XMLHttpRequest.send(<path>/dist/frontend/server/main.js)

    {
```

### tsconfig.json

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

### tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/test.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

### tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "target": "es2016",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "files": ["src/main.server.ts", "server.ts"],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not related to relative TS paths, but relative URLs.  So it is not `tsconfig` that you have to change, but your `HttpClient` calls so that you make xhr calls to absolute URLS

```
httpClient.get('/api/products'); //<= error in universal
httpClient.get('http://mydomaine.com/api/products'); //<= OK in universal
```